# MissingMethodException while using Csvhelper UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics =true configuration in c#

Tags: c#, excel, csv, csvhelper

I am using Csvhelper (version 2.16) to write the records to csv file.

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#getting-started

I want to keep leading zeros when generated csv file is opened in excel format,
so i have used UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics= true configuration while writing the csv file.

```
using (SqlDataReader dataReader ){
                        CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration
                        {
                            UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics = true
                        };

                        var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config);

                        if (dataReader != null)
                        {
                            //Write to CSV
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           //exception
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but it throws following exception

Method not found:
'Void CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration.set_UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics(Boolean)'.

What might be the problem here?

thanks,
Amol

Comment: You deployed a different version of CsvHelper than the one used to compile against.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster .Currently i am debugging in visual studio application is not deployed.

Comment: Ok now i have updated the csvhelper for all projects in my solution. now error is gone. Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you please add it as answer so i can mark it as answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A MissingMethodException almost always means that your application is running using a different version of an assembly than the assembly used to compile it against.

In this case it happened because another project, referenced by your main application, used an older version of the CsvHelper library, where that property wasn't present and thus its getter method wasn't found.

Make sure all projects in your solution reference the same version of the library, so its assemblies won't get overwritten with an older version on build.

Answer (score 1):

tested with simple data and worked as expected:

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
            {"Field1", "a string"},
            {"Field2", "00001"}
        };
        using(var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var config = new CsvConfiguration { UseExcelLeadingZerosFormatForNumerics = true };
            var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, config);
            if(data != null)
            {
                foreach(var key in data.Keys)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(key);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
                foreach (var key in data.Keys)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(data[key]);
                }
                csv.NextRecord();
            }
        }
```

the output is:

Field1,Field2

a string,="00001"

Could it be a mismatched version of the CsvHelper.dll on your deployment environment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by consolidating my NuGet packages. CsvHelper was listed there with inconsistent versions.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when application is published with "Trim Unused Code" setting enabled.

CSVHelper is not trim safe and as a result trimmer does not recognize that parts of your model classes are used by CSVHelper and can remove them (usually happens with default constructors).

To solve this, configure trimmer not to trim your assemblies. Edit your project file and add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
....
    <TrimMode>partial</TrimMode>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="MyAssembly" />
</ItemGroup>
```

More information:

[Trim Self Contained Deployments / Trimming Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-7-0)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75673682/6305294